# How can I get and change the framerate of OGRE application?

Tags: c++, frame, ogre3d, frame-rate

I am working on Ogre application that I set real time views as a background in my window. Hovewer I have question when I try to get my application's frame rate by using RenderTarget::getAverageFPS() and then I get 19.7433. Is this right frame rate ? 
and how can I change this frame rate for example to 30fps or 40fps ?

Answer (score 3):

Unless your application is locked to the screen's vsync, you can't just change your framerate. You have to optimize your rendering, so that you can render within whatever framerate you desire. Or alternatively, render less stuff.

So if you want to render a frame 30 times a second, your rendering (and everything else) must happen within 1/30th of a second.

In short: Ogre is probably not directly the *cause* of your framerate. What you're telling Ogre to *do* is.

Note that you should be checking this in an optimized, release build, not debug. Debug builds are slow (because they're for debugging).

Comment: @barzos: There is no one thing you need to do. You need to either render less stuff, make the stuff you do render simpler, or otherwise optimize your code to make it faster. Since you have not posted any code there's nothing much more than "optimize" that can be said. Your solution will be specific to *your* code; there's no magic button you can push to make your application run at a given framerate. Why do you think game development is so hard?